# Counting the characters of a string and than placing the value inside a for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop, count

I am currently taking an introductory java programming course and I have been setting the following exercise:

> *Write a program that can ask a series of questions from an array of
>   Strings. It should print a line of stars under the question, with the
>   line of stars the same length as the question printed above it.*

Below is the code that I currently have written. The starLineExercise class features a method called starLine, which I have started to write below. The starLine method needs to print as many "*" as the characters in each of the previous System.out.println commands.

I have tried to create a string object for each question, then do a count of that, and place it into the for loop, but Eclipse gives me an error saying that the count variable can not be resolved.

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class starLineExercise{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Please enter your name");
    starLine();
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    starLine();
    System.out.println("Pleae enter your age");
    starLine();
    int age = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Your name is " + name + " and your age is " + age);

}

public static void starLine(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++);
        System.out.println("*");
}
System.out.println("");
 }
}
```

Comment: Please post code showing the problem

Comment: The above code doesn't attempt to count the length of a string.  Show us how you attempt to learn the length of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter a few things in your code:

1. Save your question in a `String` before printing it.
2. Change your `starLine()` method to take a parameter, where you can pass in the length of your `String`.
3. Change the hard-coded `20` in your `starLine()` method to use this parameter.

Comment: @ReeceAkhtar: You are welcome. If you feel that this answered your question, don't forget to accept it by marking it as the correct one. If you don't accept any answers, people will be less inclined to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method which can both do the print of the question and the starts.

```
 public void printFormattedQuestion(String question);
     System.out.println(question);
     for(int i=0;i<question.length();i++) {
         System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
```

So basically you are using `length()` method which is provided by the object of type `String`, this will return count of characters in the question so you can then use it in your for loop to print as many stars as the question has characters in it.